# 5Im(iz) what does this mean?

Tags: complex-numbers

When, in my question, it says $5Im(iz)$ does this mean the coefficient of the imaginary part or does it include the $i$.

Let me elaborate:

$5Im(iz) = 5Im(ix-y)$

So would $5Im(ix-y) = 5x$ or would it be $5ix$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $\text{Re}$ and $\text{Im}$ are **always** real, so $\text{Im}$ will never give you something like $5ix$ (unless $x$ itself is purely imaginary, in which case the two $i$ would multiply to give you $-1$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $z=x+iy$

$${\rm Im}\left(iz\right)={\rm Im}\left(ix-y\right)=x={\rm Re}\left(x+iy\right)={\rm Re}z$$

Comment: Great answer! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

I your example, $5 \Im(ix-y) = 5x$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

More generally, $\Im(x+iy) = y$ and if $z = x+iy$ then $\Im(iz) = \Im(xi-y)=x$.

Comment: Thank you for your response and helpful edits :P

Comment: @LiamWiltshire you are welcome. i suggest you accept one of the answers on the question to close it correctly in the system.

Answer (score 0):

If $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $i$ is the imaginary unit, we have $\Im(a+ib)=b$.
Can you conclude?